# The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory: but the file exists

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I get a weird issue while saving a file with `writeToFile:options:error:` In the first case I get the following issue:

```
writeToFile failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “preferences.plist” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0xa12c30 {NSFilePath=file:/Users/patrick/Desktop/Untitled.fef/preferences.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0xa0d130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

But the file actually exist in that location. The file is stored in the app document file package.

**CODE: (Subclass of NSDocument)**

```
NSString *prefFile = [[[self fileURL] absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"preferences.plist"];

NSError *error;
BOOL succes = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:documentPreferences] writeToFile:prefFile options:0 error:&error];
if (!succes) {
    NSLog(@"writeToFile failed with error %@", error);
}
```

Comment: maybe a sandboxing issue?

Comment: @Volker could you elaborate more? What can I inspect it?

Comment: @Volker Sorry I was wrong about the other apps. It actually work for none of the apps.

Comment: You might want to add some code and what you have tried to make sure the file can be written to...

Comment: @Volker I've added the code to the question

Comment: @Volker I've replaced -(NSString*)absoluteString with  -(NSString*)path and it now works. The path are different: file:/Users... against /Users... I'm wondering what the first path is for

Comment: the file:// is for URLs with filePath... i will put that in answer so it can be checked an helps others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure when using any of the `...toFile`methods of various classes that you use a real path and not by mistake a file URL. You can tell these apart by looking at the path. If the path starts with `file://`it can't be used. If it starts with a slash `/` it is a regular file path. Still you might use `NSFileManager` to check if the file exists.

As in your code instead of calling `absoluteString` on `self.fileURL` call `path`.

Comment: If you have the fake path stored in NSString:
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:prog.path]; // Path with file://
NSString *realPath = [url path]; // Real path with /

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot that local paths are accessed with [myLocalNsUrlPath path] while remote/internet paths are accessed by [myRemoteNsUrlPath absoluteString]